Sitecore Not able to resolve Virtual Folder Value same as langauge code
I am trying to add es-es as Virtual folder but its going to error page.
Any way to add es-es as virtual folder or any customization we can do in Site resolver to make sitecore accept Virtual folder value as "es-es".

Did you specify a physicalFolder?

I have tried to configure the virtual directory of es-es and it works fine,
Steps to follow:

First to make sure that the ordering of the site nodes is configured in the Sitecore.config or patch file.
Always have the virtual directory path first and then the domain name that are without the virtual directory.
I could see that the es-es is a language code as by default Sitecore will consider it as language code and it will try to resolve the item in that language(es-es). In your case, it might try to access the home page item in the es-es language version.
If you want to use language code as a virtual directory, try updating the following Sitecore setting, which will help Sitecore not to consider es-es as language code.

<setting name="Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage" value="false" />
Site definition sample:
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>

 <site name="TestSiteB" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            hostName="sc.dev.local"
            virtualFolder="/es-es"
            physicalFolder="/"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/TestSiteB"
            startItem="/home"
            database="master"
            domain="extranet"
            allowDebug="true"
            cacheHtml="true"
            htmlCacheSize="150MB"
            enablePreview="true"
            enableWebEdit="true"
            enableDebugger="true"
            disableClientData="false"
           
/>
      <site name="TestSite" patch:after="site[@name='TestSiteB']"
            hostName="sc.dev.local"
            virtualFolder="/"
            physicalFolder="/"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/TestSiteA"
            startItem="/home"
            database="master"
            domain="extranet"
            allowDebug="true"
            cacheHtml="true"
            htmlCacheSize="150MB"
            enablePreview="true"
            enableWebEdit="true"
            enableDebugger="true"
            disableClientData="false"
            
/>
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

I have answered a similar kind of question in the below link
Use Language code as Virtual Path In Sitecore Site Definition
I hope this helps you :)

what will be impact of this setting on other sites.

And is there way to enable this setting for particular site.

There is already related questions , pls check it
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/38943/setting-languages-alwaysstriplanguage-to-false-via-code-for-specific-sites
